# How to ensure all three variables exists using in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

On my web site, I am showing people two images of custom motorcycles and allowing them to vote for the favorite. When they click on the button to vote, I pass the winner id, the loser id, and then the time. I use ColdFusion to figure out if the ids and time are appropriate.

My problem is with the .htaccess file. If there aren't three varibles, I want to redirect them to the start page.

```
--- is a good url
http://www.flyingpiston.com/rate/ 

--- is a good url
http://www.flyingpiston.com/rate/1502/1991/2013-4-2-4-43/

--- is NOT a good url
http://www.flyingpiston.com/rate/1502/1991/

--- my current settings
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ /index.cfm?section=rate&winnerid=$1&loserid=$2&time=$3 [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?section=rate [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^rate/ /index.cfm?section=rate [NS,L]

--- is not doing what I think it should do
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?section=rate [NS,L]
```

I think that the line immediately above should redirect to the start page if the third variable is not present.

How do I tweak my statement so that there are three variables or no variables passed?

To view the page, you can go here: http://www.flyingpiston.com/rate/ Use only the top two buttons to vote. The top left button passes three variables. The top right button passes just the winner and loser ids.

Comment: What is the advantage of not doing this directly in your CFM file with a cfif?

Comment: Steve, I don't want the URLs indexed for search. Although I will handle the error with a CFIF anyway, I want to make sure that the URLs can't be accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

It tests the full URL but in fact there are some imperfections:

This line

```
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ /index.cfm?section=rate&winnerid=$1&loserid=$2&time=$3 [NS,L]
```

Matches also an empty string as third match, and perhaps you should change it to

```
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/ /index.cfm?section=rate&winnerid=$1&loserid=$2&time=$3 [NS,L]
```

Moreover, this line:

```
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?section=rate [NS,L]
```

matches the start of the URL and not the full URL, try changing it to:

```
RewriteRule ^rate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /index.cfm?section=rate [NS,L]
```

(That is, match the whole URL using the $ -end of line-placeholder, and rewrite in both cases, with and without slash at the end). 
You can test the last regex [here](http://regexr.com?34c7h) .

Comment: I made both of your suggested changes.  The URL that I do NOT want to work, still works.  This URL should redirect to the start page...  http://www.flyingpiston.com/rate/2009/1511/